# no matching function for call to ‘Board::Board()’

Tags: c++

this erros is happening and I don't know why. 
First of all , I want to make a BattleShip game and I already got some classes and I need to implement few functions. I'm starting by drawing the board but I'm having a really bad time. If someone's interested or made this before and could give me a little help, I'd appreciate a lot. This is my final project for the semester and I got a rope on my neck.

Here's the problem.

I have my Board class

```
class Board {
public:
    Board(const string &filename);
    //bool putShip(const Ship &s);
    void moveShips();
    //bool attack(const Bomb &b);
    void display()const;
    void show()const;
    void initializeGrid();


private:
    int numLines, numColumns;
    //vector <Ship> ships;
    vector <vector<int> > board;
};
```

and my Player Class

```
class Player{
public:
    Player(string playerName, string boardFileName);
    void showBoard() const;
    //Bomb getBomb() const;
    //void attackBoard(const Bomb &b);
private:
    string name;
    Board board;
};
```

and I want to create a board by reading his dimensions from a txt (not done yet).

But when I do this:

```
Player::Player(string playerName, string boardFileName){

    name = playerName;
    board = boardFileName;

}
```

and this

```
void Player::showBoard() const{

    Board b01;

}
```

I get the following error:

no matching function for call to ‘Board::Board()’

Answer (score 2):

You have declared following constructor:

```
Board(const string &filename);
```

Due to this, default constructor was not generated. This is why you get an error in the following line:

```
Board b01;  // default ctor does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define an empty constructor for your `Board` class, or use your existing `Board(const string &filename);` constructor when defining `b01` in your `showBoard` method.

Comment: But that constructor was given as one of the "functions" to implement in the project.
        Board(const string &filename);// loads board from file 'filename'
How can I use it to print my board on the function showBoard?

Comment: @user2074085, sure, define it too but if you define that constructor, you need to create an empty constructor to be able to declare objects like `Board b01`.

Comment: Alright, lets say I'll only use the Board(const string &filename); constructor. Is it possible to create an object of Board type by specifying the file name?
The file name got all the info about the board I want to make.
Example:
random.txt:
Board 10x10

It will read the 10 per 10 and make a board. I'm not sure If Im being clear

Comment: Sure, then you can simply define it like: `Board b01("random.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

The error message occured because class Board does not have the default constructor. Nevertheless It seems it does not need to have the default constructor.

Simply change the definition of the constructor of class Player the following way

```
Player::Player(string playerName, string boardFileName) 
    : name( playerName ), board( boardFileName )
{
}
```

As for member function showBoard then there is no any need to create a local object b01 because it seems you have to output the board that corresponds to the data member board of the class. Or you could use the copy constrauctor to create a local object as for example

```
void Player::showBoard() const
{
    Board b01( board );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Any chance of you helping me configuring the function to print the board with the info specified on txt?

Comment: @Verance I ma sorry. I ahve not understood what you said.

Comment: I need few help to make the board. Do you have skype or something?

Comment: @Verance You may ask a new question here in this forum.